# jQuery function to flip an image on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've written some css to flip an image. It's working fine, but I want to convert it to a function so that I can call that function in an `onclick` event.

A demo of what I have so far can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/ggUue/1/

Here's the HTML for the image:

```
<div class="f1_container">
    <div class="shadow f1_card">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/48/0b/14/dolphin-view-chalets.jpg" style="height: 281px; width: 450px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">Some text inside here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.f1_container {
    position: relative;
    margin:10px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 281px;
    z-index : 1;
    float:left;
}
.f1_container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
.f1_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.f1_container:hover .f1_card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
body{width:2000px}
```

Comment: I use this CSS on my site as a content "slider" on the home page. Nice stuff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pretty simple to add this to your current solution:

**CSS**

Replace the `:hover` state with a class:

```
.f1_container:hover .f1_card {}
/* becomes */
.f1_container.active .f1_card {}
```

**JavaScript**

Add this JavaScript part that toggles the new class on click:

```
$('.f1_container').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/YaUPs/)