# Preventing flipping back when using jQuery

Tags: jquery

it was difficult to give it a good short title, so here are the details:

I am trying to make it so that when I click on a div, it flips to reveal the "back side".
I've looked at a similar question below(link), and it works perfectly, but I wanna make it so that when I have something to interact with(i.e. link) on the back side, it doesn't flip over to the front again when clicking on it. Also, instead of flipping back to the front on click, I want it to flip over when the user clicks anywhere outside that flipping div. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Also, will this effect page loading? Are there any quicker solutions?

I
[jquery-function-to-flip-an-image-on-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274030/jquery-function-to-flip-an-image-on-click)

Comment: Add a class or set a `.data-` attribute when you flip it, and in your click handler don't flip if that class/attribute is already set.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/AMNKL/ (click top and bottom of the blue box)

JS

```
$("body").click(function () {
    $(".someclass").removeClass("flipped");

});

$(".someclass").click(function () {
    flip($(this));
    return false;
});

function flip(item) {
    if (!item.hasClass("flipped")) {
        $(".someclass").removeClass("flipped");
        item.addClass("flipped");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm solving something else :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know If I got your question right but I assume that you only want the card to flip back if there is no link in your card.
If you already know that the backside of your cards have links or not , you could put a class 'hasLink' to tell your application not to flip the card back.

```
$('.f1_container').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        isActive = $this.hasClass('active'),
        hasLink = $this.hasClass('hasLink'),
        checkLink = function () {
            return ($this.find('.backSideOfCard').find(a).length >= 0)
        };

    if(isActive && !hasLink)
    {
        $('.active').not('.hasLink').removeClass('active');
        //Add this check only if you add your links dynamically  
        if(checklink()) {
           $this.addClass('hasLink');
        }
        return false;
    }
    if(!isActive)
   {
        $this.addClass('active');
   }

});
```

Finally if you only want to flip the card back by clicking outside the flipped card if it has a link you could do something like this

```
$(body).on('click', '.f1_container:not(.hasLink)', function(){
   $('.hasLink').removeClass('active');
});
```

The Class names are probably not right though; but I hope that you could reach the behaviour that you want for your app with probably some tweaks on this code; and even better grasp how to perform checks on classes.
Ajios !